# Async Action Creator Testing with Jest with Axios

Tags: redux, jestjs

I try to test authentication async action creator with JEST but I have some error response "Error: Network Error". I try to change server url but it isn't work . this application is authentication with jwt when user has login. Server will response with jwt to client.
this is my action creator and test code.

```
//TEST

import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
// import expect from 'expect';
import { userActions } from '../actions';
import { userConstants } from '../constants';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

describe('Async action creator test', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    fetchMock.reset();
    fetchMock.restore();
  });

  it('creates LOGIN_SUCCESS when sign in has been done', () => {
    fetchMock.postOnce('/api/sign-in', { body: {token: 'jwt'},headers:  { 'content-type': 'application/json' } });
    const store = mockStore({ user: [] });

    const expectedActions = [
      { type: userConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST, user: {username: 'testUsername'} },
      { type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, token: 'jwt'},
    ];

    return store.dispatch(userActions.login('testUsername', 'testPassword')).then(() => {
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
    });
  });
})


// ACTION CREATOR
import axios from 'axios';
import { userConstants } from '../constants'

const login = (username, password) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(request({username}));

    return axios.post('http://www.example.com/api/sign-in', {username, password})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        dispatch(success(response));
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        dispatch(failure(error.toString()));
      });
  };

  function request(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST, user } }
  function success(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, user } }
  function failure(error) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE, error } }
};

export const userActions = {
  login,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You tests are trying to perform actual XHR calls which is usually not the desired behaviour, since it's about unit testing.

There are different viable approaches to skip and mock the actual network requests.

Since I understand you want to include real `axios` calls in your tests, you might consider mocking the network requests with an HTTP mocking library like [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock).

Answer (score 0):

axios is used for http requests in your code, however, fetch-mock is used for http request mock in your test. So, to fix this issue, you need to:

1. Replace axios with fetch in your code. or:
2. Replace fetch-mock with moxios in your test.